# Setting Android AutoCompleteTextView position relative to anchor view

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've got an android AutoCompleteTextView (actually extended) and I'd like to control where the popup list of suggestions appears. For example above or below my anchor view.

Currently, the autocomplete seems to prefer below the anchor view unless the data it is trying to display needs more room (and that room is available above). Is there a way to set it to always appear in a certain orientation regardless of the size of data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this:

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               myAutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();      
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myAutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myAutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
            }
        });
```